Get nth position of the child component in React?
I have a PagesContainer component that renders multiple Page components like this:
<PagesContainer>
  <Page />
  <Page />
  <Page />
  <Page />
</PagesContainer>

I want each Page component to know its respective page number (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4).
I preferably do not want to pass it down as a prop (e.g., <Page number={1} />) because I will be programatically generating some <Page /> through loops, but not all of them. I also want to be able to reorder these pages freely and have each render the right number just by moving its position in the parent.
Ideally, I'd like a hook like so: const currentPage = useGetCurrentPage().
How do I get the <Page />'s position in the parent?

I think you can access the order of children with document.getElementById or something similar

You can map() over the props.children, then use the index from map to pass along to the Child using cloneElement.
I've incremented the index by 1 since your example does not start from 0.


const App = () => (
    <PagesContainer>
        <Page />
        <Page />
        <Page />
        <Page />
    </PagesContainer>
)

const PagesContainer = (props) => props.children.map(
    (Child, index) => React.cloneElement(Child, { index: index + 1 })
);

const Page = ({ index }) => (<p>Page #{index}</p>);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>




You can use a forwardRef and useImperativeHandle and useState.

export default function Test() {
  const parentRef = useRef(null);
  const childRef = useRef([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (childRef.current !== null) {
      childRef.current.forEach((cr, i) => {
        cr.setPageNumber(i + 1);
      });
    }
  });
  const addToRefs = (el) => {
    childRef.current.push(el);
  };
  return (
    <div ref={parentRef}>
      <Child ref={addToRefs} />
      <Child ref={addToRefs} />
      <Child ref={addToRefs} />
      <Child ref={addToRefs} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = forwardRef(function Child(props, ref) {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      setPageNumber(n) {
        setPageNumber(n);
      },
    };
  });
  return <div>{pageNumber}</div>;
});

